# Using createRef in react-native with typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-ref

I am trying to figure out how I need to use `React.createRef()` in react native with typescript as following code throws errors

```
 // ...

  circleRef = React.createRef();

  componentDidMount() {
    this.circleRef.current.setNativeProps({
      someProperty: someValue
    });
  }

  // ...
```

Currently following errors are thrown for `this.circleRef.current.setNativeprops`

> [ts] Object is possibly 'null'. (property)
>   React.RefObject<{}>.current: {} | null

and

> [ts] Property 'setNativeProps' does not exist on type '{}'. any

any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The first issue can be solved with a null check before proceeding with your logic since `React.createRef()` can also return `null`:

```
componentDidMount() {
  if(this.circleRef !== null && this.circleRef.current !== null) {
    this.circleRef.current.setNativeProps({
      someProperty: someValue
    });
  }
}
```

The second is solved by passing the class name of the Node element for which you want to create a reference. For example, if your referenced element is a `<Text>`, then do:

```
circleRef = React.createRef<Text>();
```

This way, `circleRef` will be correctly typed and `setNativeProps` will exist **if and only if the referenced component is directly backed by a native view**:

> The methods [of `current`] are available on most of the default components provided by React Native. Note, however, that they are not available on composite components that aren't directly backed by a native view. This will generally include most components that you define in your own app. - [Direct Manipulation - React Native documentation](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/direct-manipulation.html#other-native-methods)

Comment: So, there is no way of using the type of a custom component in createRef? Like: `const customCompRef = React.createRef<CustomComponentType>()`

Answer (score 10):

You can add Typescript typings to a React Native Ref  like this:

```
const textInputRef: React.RefObject<TextInput> = React.createRef();
```